# Reduce image quality in delphi

Tags: delphi

hello I'm trying to reduce the quality of a jpg image in delphi, the problem is that my code I get this error E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'string'

My code is this:

```
   TForm1.Button4Click procedure (Sender: TObject);
   var
     imagen2: TJpegImage;
   begin

     image2: = TJpegImage.Create;
     imagen2.Assign ('c:/test.jpg');
     imagen2.CompressionQuality: = 60;
     imagen2.SaveToFile ('c:/test.jpg');

   end;
```

Someone can help me to correct the error?

Comment: It's not Assign, its's LoadFromFile.

Comment: Assign expects a similar object. Use LoadFromFile as @bummy comments.

Comment: PS: if you Ctrl+click on "Assign" it will take you to the method declaration, and you can see there what kind of parameter it expects.

Comment: Warning: I guess you actually want to reduce the size, by reducing the quality. "60" is quite an arbitrary value. You might want to use an algorithm like this to make sure you decrease the size evenly, while the quality remains overall similar on all your images: https://github.com/AdminUser0/ImageQuality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please learn to actually read the words in the error message. In this case, it's quite clear that you're trying to pass a string to something that expects a `TPersistent`. Examining the code that causes the error would make it very clear that `TJpegImage.Assign` is not expecting a filename, but something else.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage) makes it clear that to load something from a file to a `TJpegImage` you use [`LoadFromFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic.LoadFromFile):

```
imagen2 := TJpegImage.Create;
imagen2.LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg');
```

It also clearly documents what [`TJpegImage.Assign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.Assign) is expecting, and what it is intended to do (including two links to code examples, one in Delphi and one in C++).

```
procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
```

> Copies the jpeg image object and creates a new reference tp the internal data source object.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the error message:

```
Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'string'
```

That is quite clear. The compiler expected TPersistent, but you passed string. The Assign method does indeed expect a TPersistent. To use assign you need to have two graphic objects. You don't have that. You've got a graphic object and a file name.

So Assign is not useful here. What you need to do is the inverse of SaveToFile which is LoadFromFile.

```
imagen2.LoadFromFile('c:\test.jpg'); 
imagen2.CompressionQuality := 60;
imagen2.SaveToFile ('c:\test.jpg');
```

Don't be afraid of compiler errors. Read them, and try to work out what they mean.